# Throwing a child class object as exception

Tags: c++, c++11

While reading exceptions, I came to know that while throwing an object, an object is always constructed based upon static type information. How can we throw a child class object if an exception occurs, then? Here are some lines from More Effective C++ book:

> ```
> class Widget{...};
>
> class SpecialWidget: public Widget {...};
>
> void passAndThrowWidget()
> {
>     SpecialWidget localSpecialWidget;
>     ...
>     Widget& rw = localSpecialWidget;
>     throw rw; // this throws an exception of type widget!
> }
> ```
>
> Here a Widget exception is thrown, even though rw refers to a `SpecialWidget`. That's because rw's static type is Widget, not Special-Widget. That rw actually refers to a S`pecialWidget` is of no concern to your compilers; all they care about is rw's static type.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9830220) explains why it is happening but doesn't provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: Why not? It's a reference to the base class part of `localSpecialWidget`.

Comment: This is a pseudo code where rw reference is holding a child class object.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis why wouldn't it? Base class references can bind to derived class objects.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9830220/831878

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Throwing a derived class by reference does not work when catching base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830220/c-throwing-a-derived-class-by-reference-does-not-work-when-catching-base-clas)

Comment: Whops sorry I read it the other way around ;)

Answer (score 5):

You would need to add

```
virtual void throwYourself() = 0;
```

to the Widget class. And implement it with

```
void SpecialWidget::throwYourself() override { throw *this; }
```

then, you can call throwYourself() on a base pointer object. Whether this is a good design is a different question to which I have no answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and this is rather important to the compiler. It must make sure that `throw` and `catch` are matched. The restriction on `throw` means that the compiler at least knows the static type of thrown objects.

Now, you may think to yourself, "but `catch` does support RTTI". There's a simple explanation. `catch (Foo&)` needs to catch the thrown type, and a finite number of base classes. But if `throw` needed to deal with derived classes at runtime, there's an infinite number of possible derived classes.